Difference between func.apply(this, args) and func(...args) in closures
I came across the following thing while trying to understand some concepts of working with closures.
When I was reading about memoization/throttling, people were using func.apply(this, args) in closures.
Here are some examples from 2 different sources:
function memoize(func) {
  const cache = {}
  return function(...args) {
    const key = JSON.stringify(args)
    if (cache[key]) {
      return cache[key]
    } else {
      const result = func.apply(this, args) // (*)
      cache[key] = result
      return result
    }
  }
}

and
function throttle(func, interval) {
  let isRunning = false;

  return function (...args) {
    if (!isRunning) {
      isRunning = true;
      func.apply(this, args); // (*)

      setTimeout(() => {
        isRunning = false;
      }, interval);
    }
  };
}

So my question is: can we use func(...args) instead? And what is the actual difference if we would call func with spread-operator instead of apply?

Does func access this?

In the examples itself — no. But theoreticaly. In which cases would that make a difference? If we would use it from some object methods and it would rely on some object properties? Am I right?

A function can always access this. If func doesn't access this, func.apply(this, args) and func(...args) are equivalent. In JavaScript, standalone functions can also use this and that's not unusual. You don't need an object. You can also have nested functions or functions that are called in HTML. There are many other examples.

You don't care about this if you use the spread syntax:
function memoize(func) {
  const cache = {}
  return function(...args) {
    return cache[JSON.stringify(args)] ??= func(...args);
  }
}


If you use func(...args), you won't be setting the this value for this call of func and its value will depend on whether you're in strict mode.
In strict mode, it would be undefined but in sloppy mode, it's the window object. See Default binding of the "this" keyword in strict mode
